# Using a definite integral, to create a specific recurrence relation.

Tags: calculus, integration, recurrence-relations, definite-integrals

Hello i have the integral:

$$y_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+5}dx$$ where $ n=1,2,3,4,....,\infty$

I need to show that the integral can be represented by the recurrence relation below;

$$y_n= \frac1n-5y_{n-1}$$

I started by doing integration by parts but still cannot find the relation. I am assuming it has to do with the integration by parts method where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $$y_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+5}dx$$

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+5}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+5-5)}{x+5}dx=\int_0^1x^{n-1}dx-5\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5}dx$$  as $x+5\ne0$

---

Alternatively,

$$\text{So,}y_n+5y_{n-1}$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+5}dx+5\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5}dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+5)}{x+5}dx=\int_0^1x^{n-1}dx$$  as $x+5\ne0$

Comment: You likely mean $y_n + 5y_{n-1}$

Comment: @gt6989b, thanks for your observation. Rectified

Comment: Why is your second step yn+5yn-1?

Comment: @RyanRoss, observe the proposition in the Question to proved or you can  check the edited answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thank you sorry I did not refresh the page.